# Time-based Workflow Question

Tags: workflow, time-dependent-workflow

Is it possible to activate a time based workflow on the day OF a date field? The options are "before" or "after" a date.

Will "1 hour after" a date work?
OR "0 days after" a date

Comment: this question is easily amenable to testing in your sandbox - have you tried that?

Comment: Yea but sometimes the timebased workflow doesn't fire right away. I was just trying to get a quick answer. It still hasn't fired and it meets all the criteria needed. Do you have an answer? @crop1645

Comment: see https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=workflow_time_action_considerations.htm&language=en to see if any of this applies to you. I've used the x hours after before and it works fine; never tried 0 days after

Answer (score 1):

I believe "0 days after" should work:

> If you schedule an action for 0 Days After a date, there may be a
>   delay from the time represented by the date field before the action
>   group executes.

(https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=process_limits_scheduled.htm&language=en_US)

This is for Process Builder schedule actions, but I think it's the same for Workflows.